# manpath: error: unable to read SDK settings for '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk'

Tags: terminal, iterm2, macos-catalina

After upgrade to the new Mac OS Catalina, this error happens when I open the iTerm2.

> MacBookPro 2015 Mid
>
> macOS Catalina
>
> Version 10.15

[image: error in the iTerm2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I run the following command, it works.

```
xcode-select --install
```